# When a Firebase node syncs, is the full new value sent to the server or just the difference?

Tags: firebase

And does it work the same way when an object is being updated via a callback like `ref.on('value', ...`?

I tried to figure it out in myself in the Chrome dev tools but wasn't able to.

This makes a difference for me because I'm working on an app where users might store large amounts of text.  If only diffs are sent over the wire, it's a lot more lightweight and I can sync much more frequently.  If full values are sent, I wouldn't want to do that.

Answer (score 4):

When data is written, the Firebase server currently sends all the data being written down to the server. If you write a large object, and then rewrite the whole object with the same object again, the entire object will be sent over the wire (This may be changing in the future, but that's the current implementation).

When sending data from the server back out to other clients, we do do some optimization and don't transmit some of the duplicate data.

Firebase is designed to allow you to granularly access data. I would strongly suggest you address into the data that is changing and only update the relevant portions. For example:

```
//inefficient method:
ref.set(HUGE_BLOCK_OF_JSON);

//efficient method:
ref.child("a").child("b").child("c").set(SOME_SMALL_PIECE_OF_DATA);
```

When you address into a piece of data, only that small piece is transmitted and rebroadcast to other clients.

Firebase is intended for true real-time apps where updates are made as soon as data changes. If you find yourself intentionally caching changes for a while and saving them as big blobs for performance reasons, you should probably be breaking up your data and only writing the relevant portions.

Comment: So you're suggesting that a node that holds only a block of text should be arbitrarily split into a list of text nodes and managed on the client side?

Comment: To be clear, I don't mean JSON. (Storing JSON in one node almost seems like defeating the point of firebase.) I mean something like a 10-page essay, that is strictly one block of flowing text.

Comment: Yes, if you set a giant string to another giant string, it'll send down the entire new string, not a diff. Firebase is intended for syncing structured data, so if you have a giant block of text that you want synched / edited piecemeal, you should try to break it up in logical ways.

Are you trying to build a collaborative text editor? If so we may be able to help you out. Please email me: andrew at firebase dot com.